a foul smells lingers 1 day AFTER showering
i cannot find it anywhere. but after 1 day it start to smell bad for three days. then the smells go aways. then when i shower again the cycle starts. idk where it is comming from
i also can't explain it properly but i think it is similar to mildew
what i have tried is

removing dirty clothes
cleaning drain with hydrocholic acid.

i havent found a solution i just wait for 3 days till the smell goes away

also adding to this it starts when i turn on the ac after showering. i also can't turn it off because it is too hot in our country

Are there any other fixtures besides the shower that cause this?

@Matthew i have a sink there. i tried to smell it there but i dont think the smell is comming from the bathroom. the smell is in my bedroom

it's possible that the shower box (walls) , tray (floor pan) or riser (pipes) is leaking. check for damp where it doesn't belong

Have you tried to drop a little bleach in fully after you shower?   I have had an issue with the ptrap drying out quickly and odors from that.   I am not sure that is your issue but worth a cup of bleach

I suspect improper plumbing venting. Beneath each drain is what's called a trap. The trap is U or P shaped and fills with water to prevent gasses in your sewer pipes from wafting into the room.
The plumbing vents provide air behind the drains so that when water rushes through the pipes it doesn't create suction behind the pipes in your fixtures.
If there is improper venting then the water rushing in the drain can cause suction in your pipes that sucks water out of the traps. When the traps are not full then foul smelling sewer gasses will seep up the drains.
Perhaps this happens with your shower because it has a sufficiently high flow of drain water and a venting problem. Then after a few days you have used sufficient other fixtures to refill you traps and stop the gasses.
Consider an experiment. Run your shower at a trickle for a long time. This will create high volume of water but not at a short time. So if there is a leak somewhere leading to the smell then the trickle shower should cause it. But if it's related to the rush of water sucking out a trap then the trickle shower should not cause the smell.
